# Why are the number of ways of permuting (in a circle), a flippable object $=(n-1)!/2$ where $n$ is number of objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For instance if we have a necklace with different coloured beads (it is flippable) why should we divide $(n-1)!$ by two, meaning we are not even considering the permutations of the flipped necklace (to be extra) in the first place to be cancelled out of the total permutations.

I have a small idea about it though....I think it is because we get 2 permutations by arranging objects circularly in just one way, just by flipping it...not sure though

Answer (score 1):

In general when counting permutations in a circle, a rotation of any one permutation is not considered to be a different permutation; thus the position of the first bead is immaterial, and so the number of permutations is $\,(n-1)!\,$

On top of that, your necklaces are "flippable", which implies that a reflection of any one permutation is not considered to be a different permutation; since every permutation has two reflections, we have to reduce our count by half, so our final answer will be $\,\frac{(n-1)!}{2}.\,$

Note that the last step assumes that there is indeed a reflection for each permutation, which isn't true if the necklace only has one or two beads, so the formula only holds for $\,n\ge 3;\,$ for $\,n=1\,$ and $\,n=2,\,$ the correct number would just be $\,(n-1)!=1.\,$[My thanks to N.F. Taussig for pointing out the need for this addendum.]

Comment: This is true when $n \geq 3$.  For the cases $n = 1$ and $n = 2$, there is only one possible necklace since the necklace is its own reflection.

Comment: Thanks for catching that; I've added a note to the solution to reflect those exceptions.